# Cómo contar palabras en Android?

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen podemos ver que hay dos cajas de texto en las cuales vamos a ingresar los nombres y apellidos, al darle clic al botón imprimir deberá imprimir el nombre y apellidos completos y deberá decir el numero de palabras que contiene el nombre.

Comment: Puedes poner lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Si no sabes por donde empezar, la clase `String` tiene un método para contar el número de caracteres de una cadena,  **[aquí hay un ejemplo bien clarito de cómo funciona](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-length-method-example/)**

Comment: Juan, es importante leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.  Te invitobtambién realices el tour para que te enteres comonfunciona el sitio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres contar el numero de palabras, podrías usar `split`, este devolverá un array del cual posteriormente obtienes la longitud:

```
//nombre es el texto de tu editText
//spliteas los espacios para ver las separaciones de nombres
String temp[] = nobre.split(" ");
int cantidadNombres = temp.length;
```

Comment: No es necesario eso, con que hagas `nombre.lenght()` obtienes la longitud de la cadena directamente, ¿por qué hay que hacer split sobre ella? Eso serviría si quisieras contar el número de palabras separadas por espacio que tiene la cadena, no su longitud.

Comment: Si lees la pregunta, pide el numero de palabras, no de letras. `y deberá decir el numero de palabras que contiene el nombre.`

Answer (score 1):

Con `palabra.length()` se puede obtener el numero de letras de una palabra, en tu ejemplo seria algo así

```
String nombre = textnombre.getText().toString();
        String apellido = textapellido.getText().toString();
        String nombrecompleto = nombre + " " + apellido;

        Toast.makeText(this,"Su nombre completo es " + nombrecompleto,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,"El tamaño es " + nombrecompleto.length(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```